# How to format table cell to have rounded corners?

Tags: xcode, uitableview, xcode4

I want rounded corners for my **Table Cell View**. So I just set the background to transparent but this removes the whole background of the cell.

Any idea how to do that using the visual editor?

[image]

Comment: Maybe you can set the corner radius for the cell's layer? Just a thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some ways to achieve that:

- override drawRect in your custom tableViewCell class. This is drawing by hand, very nasty ;) I'll post an example code below for a rounded corner background.
- put an imageView in the background and add a picture with round corners to the cell. (Background is transparent of course). The problem with transparent backgrounds is performance.

**example code for a backround with round corners**

```
float radius = 10.0;

CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();   
rect = CGRectInset(rect, 1.0f, 1.0f);

CGContextBeginPath(context);
CGContextSetGrayFillColor(context, 0.0, 0.8);
CGContextMoveToPoint(context, CGRectGetMinX(rect) + radius, CGRectGetMinY(rect));
CGContextAddArc(context, CGRectGetMaxX(rect) - radius, CGRectGetMinY(rect) + radius, radius, 3 * M_PI / 2, 0, 0);
CGContextAddArc(context, CGRectGetMaxX(rect) - radius, CGRectGetMaxY(rect) - radius, radius, 0, M_PI / 2, 0);
CGContextAddArc(context, CGRectGetMinX(rect) + radius, CGRectGetMaxY(rect) - radius, radius, M_PI / 2, M_PI, 0);
CGContextAddArc(context, CGRectGetMinX(rect) + radius, CGRectGetMinY(rect) + radius, radius, M_PI, 3 * M_PI / 2, 0);

CGContextClosePath(context);
CGContextFillPath(context);
```